# C++ pointers memory usage

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

Keep going around circles, but I am still unclear about this. Have a feeling about the answer; but not sure. Which code below consumes more memory? [Should be the former, if I am correct.]

```
double x;
double* y = new double(x);
```

OR

```
double x;
double* y = &x;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the former, two `double`s exist (`x`, and the one pointed to by `y`). `x` is allocated on the stack, and `y` on the heap.

In the latter, only one `double` exists (`x`, also pointed to by `y`). There are no heap allocations involved here.

So, on the face of it, you are correct.

**In both cases**, there exists one `double` on the stack, and one `double*` also on the stack. The difference between the two is that in the first case, there is **also** a `double` allocated on the heap (the one allocated by `new double(x)`). Therefore the first case requires more storage.

Comment: Are you sure? If we had to consider the RAM memory consumed overall by such a code (think millions of such doubles)...I need to know for sure if the former is correct. I understand that a pointer itself consumes a fixed 8 bytes (say, on a 64-bit system); so when you look at it like that, the first code appears to uses 2 x 8 (or is it 3 x 8 because of the new on the right hand side of the assignment in the second line?) bytes, while the second also uses 2 x 8 bytes. Which is correct?

Comment: You ended your comment saying "second case requires more storage". Is that a typo? Did you mean, "first case.." instead?

Answer (score 7):

The following consumes `sizeof( double ) + sizeof( double* )` plus `sizeof( double )` on the heap:

```
double x;
double* y = new double(x);
```

The following consumes `sizeof( double ) + sizeof( double* )`:

```
double x;
double* y = &x;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double x;
double* y = &x;
```

will take `sizeof(double) + sizeof(void*)`

```
double x;
double* y = new double(x);
```

will take `sizeof(double) + sizeof(double) + sizeof(void*)`. Also allocates memory from the heap via `new`. There will also be more bookkeeping overhead based on the heap allocator (especially if it breaks up a contiguous free chunk), and it will be slower.

Answer (score 1):

The first one. There are two doubles and one pointer (usually long int)

In the second one you have only one double and one pointer

Answer (score 1):

In this example:

```
double x;
double* y = new double(x);
```

you have the memory space for `x`, for the pointer `y`, and the new allocated memory that stores a copy of `x`, and is pointed by `y`.

In this example:

```
double x;
double* y = &x;
```

you have the memory space for `x`, for the pointer `y` which points to `x`. This uses less space.

Answer (score 0):

first allocate space for 1 double at first line, then at second line allocates space for 1 pointer and another double, and copies value from the old one.
The latter allocate space for 1 double and for a pointer.
So first is more memory consuming.